# Spring boot - JPA matcher not working when I set the "username" variable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I starting to learn the spring boot. I tried many times that I haven't been solved one problem. Users class has username variable. I want to check if username exist our database and throw exception as error message.

```
 ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matchingAll()
            .withMatcher("username", exact())
            .withIgnorePaths("id");

    Example<Users> example = Example.of(users, matcher);
    List<Users> find =  usersRepository.findAll(example);

    System.out.println("Find users: "+find.size());
```

I set the username variable on matchers. when I run the api and show the log. you can see below:

```
User payload: Users{id=0, firstName='Homer', lastName='Simpsons', username='bart.skate', email='homer.sleeper@gmail.com', password='@bcd1234'}
Find users: 0
User payload: Users{id=0, firstName='Homer', lastName='Simpsons', username='bart.skate', email='homer.simpsons@gmail.com', password='@bcd1234'}
Find users: 0
```

First users has been created. so I tried to create new user again same username. it wasn't find the username.

I hope someone help to explain for me. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of database do you use?

Comment: @dawidklos I using h2 database that it save the memory on my machine.

Comment: just for checking - switch to h2 on-disk database, and see if it will still occur, if not, I will provide a wide explanation in answer why is that.